# Python: Display index in a 2D array of all elements

Tags: python, arrays

If I have a list/array such as:

```
B = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[4,3,2,4]]
```

(there are 50 elements in total)

I only want to show the 2nd value of each element. e.g. 3,4,2

I have tried something like `B([:,2])` but I keep getting an error `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"`

I was thinking I might have to use some sort of loop?

Comment: Tuple indexing works for numpy arrays. Lists don't take those. Instead, you can index each sublist in a list comprehension.

Comment: `print([i[2] for i in B])`

Comment: I have done that and it is showing all values in column 3, but If I want to change all the values in column 3 to '0' how would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions for the rescue:

```
result = [i[2] for i in B]
```

Comment: I now have it showing me the 2nd value in each element but do you know how I would replace that value (say with 0) and then write the data back to my original array/list B?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x

```
list(zip(*B))[2]
```

In Python 2.x

```
zip(*B)[2]
```

Output:

```
(3, 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `List Comprehension` :

```
#`n` is the row
>>> [row[n] for row in B]
```

#driver value :

```
IN : B = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[4,3,2,4]]
IN : n = 2
OUT : [3, 4, 2]
```